# relationship between null space of a matrix and null space of after translation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.
The null space is defined as $N(A) := \{x|Ax = 0\} $.

In my particular example, the rank of $N(A)$ is 1.

I can obtain the basis $b_1$ of $N(A)$ via LU/QR decompose $A$.

I also need to obtain the basis of null space of a linear translated matrix $B = A+c, c\in \mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$.The matrix vector sum is defined as every row vector of $A$ add offset $c$.

Wondering how much can I get to reuse from calculating $b_1$ without doing everything all from scratch. As $c$ might vary and needs to the same thing again and again.

Comment: How exactly do you translate the matrix $A$? The way it is written right now, the dimensions in the addition do not fit.

Comment: Thank you, apologize for my mistake, corrected the shape

Comment: I think it still does not work this way: $A$ is $m\times n$ and $c$ is $1\times n$ in order to be able to add them (in the usual sense) the dimensions have to be the same. Are you looking for the solutions of $Ax=c$?

Comment: Every row vector of $A$ is shifted by $c$ as they both live in a $n$ dimension

Comment: Ah, I see. I have the feeling that there is not much you can use from the computation of $N(A)$. I think that the perturbation can have ranks 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: Within my context, the rank of $N(B)$ is always going to be 1, if that’s helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116652/discussion-between-christian-and-peng-yu).